# Hashtag URL rewrites a la Twitter & SheandHim.com

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

Ok, I'm wondering if anyone can point out any good resources for implementing hashtag URLs similar to how Twitter and the site http://www.sheandhim.com/#/news handle links.

The goal on sheandhim.com is to have all content exist on the page at load so that "navigating" to other areas of the site does not force a page reload (which would stop the music which is playing).

I have the same need for a project I'm working on and have not been able to find any good info (maybe my Google-fu is weak) on replicating this kind of effect.

I should add that I am developing this on WordPress so ideally it would be friendly with WordPress (a tall order I suppose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the other answers are true in a sense, but for the benefit of anyone else with the same question, I'm looking at the SheandHim.com source code and there is alot of very well written code that answers alot of questions.

In case the site has changed by the time someone is reading this, there is alot of custom javascript work done, but the backbone of the whole thing is this jQuery plugin (called jQuery DeepLinking:

http://www.thetutorialblog.com/jquery/deep-linking-with-jquery/

A demo can be seen here:

http://www.thetutorialblog.com/demos/jQueryDeepLinking

FYI: the method of the plugin calls the contents of any page via AJAX request to the relative path.  This means that **it IS possible** to do this with WordPress because the PHP is still processed as normal HTML which the AJAX fetch of the plugin can grab and use to output the AJAX `window.location.has` as the previous posters correctly identified.  But there's alot of other stuff going on here as well.

Answer (score 1):

First read the hashstring using `window.location.hash`, then make an AJAX request to fetch the data that matches the hashstring.

How exactly you would mix this up with WordPress, I don't know. I don't believe WordPress is made for stuff like that.

Comment: Our answers are almost identical. Though, after some hesitation, I removed part about wordpress :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can access passed hash by calling `window.location.hash`.

Then you're free to make any ajax calls you want and update the page accordingly.